# call function to function by variables

Tags: php

Hello I tried to echo the output of a function by another function and I wrote this code:

```
$users = new user();
class user{
  public function userlist(){
    //Here is my sql action and then it send the result as output
    echo $output;
  }
}
```

Now I have a class which contains the template of the site, this file passes through every pages.

```
$html = new html();
class html{
  public function output($output){
    //echoing some html styles and the template html code..
    echo '<div id="body">';
    $output;
    echo "</div>";
  }
}
```

Now the `$output` should be in the html page inside the `<div id="body">`, the problem is that `$output`'s HTML is echoed before the div and is not inside the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way:

```
class user{
  public function userlist(){
    //Here is my sql action and then it send the result as output
    return $output;
  }
}

class html{
  public function output($output){
    //echoing some html styles and the template html code..
    echo '<div id="body">';
    echo $output;
    echo "</div>";
  }
}

class controller {
  function handler(){
    $users = new user();
    $html = new html();
    $html->output($users->userlist());
  }
}
```

Now without modifying the `user` class, you could use output buffering to temporary hold the `$users` object output, and then output it at a more convenient time:

```
class user{
  public function userlist(){
    //Here is my sql action and then it send the result as output
    echo $output;
  }
}

class controller {
  function handler(){
    $users = new user();
    $html = new html();
    ob_start();
    $users->userlist();
    $output = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    $html->output($output);
  }
}
```

I don't think you can get the expected result without modifying the `html::output` method however.

See the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) on the `ob_*` functions for an explanation of their semantics.

Addendum: please note that many frameworks already use output buffering internally. The documentation states that buffers are stackable (ie. you may start a new buffering on top of another running one), but just be careful to start and end your buffers properly so as to not mess up your framework inner state (and ultimately your output), if you are using one.

Comment: it doesnt helped. Thank anyway.

Comment: The previous revision of this answer used `print` as a method name, which is a reserved keyword, I fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to echo $output also

```
public function($output){
 //echoing some html styles and the template html code..
  echo '<div id="body">';
  echo $output;
  echo "</div>";
}
```

or use just one liner

```
public function($output){
  //echoing some html styles and the template html code..
  echo '<div id="body">'. $output . "</div>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the variable incorrectly. As it is a string, you should simply append or concatenate it within the output as follows:

```
class html{
public function($output){
    //echoing some html styles and the template html code..
    echo '<div id="body">'.$output."</div>";
    }
}
```

Additionally, in your first function, you simply output the value of $output rather than actually save it to a variable. If you want to display things in order, you should either save the data to a variable you can access properly elsewhere (say in a return statement) or output your initial stream, then run the function, then output the remaining stream.

Comment: thank you but regular text or html is passing good, but when we do a while function that include mysql connection and output a list of names its send $output before the div and not inside him.